# Muting an Application on a Mac

Tags: macos, audio, mute

Is it possible to mute just a single application (ex. Safari) on Mac while letting other application's sound continue to run through?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [Audio Hijack Pro](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijackpro/):

[image: Audio Hijack Pro screenshot]

It's an advanced mixer initially meant for recording an application's audio.

You can adjust the volume of each application separately and also mute them. It's also **fully AppleScriptable**, so I guess you could associate keyboard shortcuts to mute a given set of apps.

Answer (score 3):

I tried [BackgroundMusic](https://github.com/kyleneideck/BackgroundMusic) and it works like a charm (and it's free!)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the (mis-?)fortune to be running 10.4 on a PowerPC Mac, then you can still use Rogue Amoeba's old [Detour](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/detour/) product (now free.)

You can also accomplish this with their [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) product, in a roundabout way, by hijacking Safari and then not enabling any Airfoil speakers.

(It's a shame they didn't revamp Detour, once they'd come up with a new way not using APE, to instantly hijack the sound. I too used to divert Safari to shut up annoying embedded MIDI and Flash. But I can recommend [ClickToFlash](http://rentzsch.github.com/clicktoflash/) for handling the latter!)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something simpler (and cheaper) than Audio Hijack, I just came across an app called [SoundBunny](https://www.prosofteng.com/soundbunny-mac-volume-control/). I have not tried it, but it looks like a good alternative for those who just want to control apps' volumes and don't need the recording capabilities of Audio Hijack.

Comment: Please don't recommend programs **you haven't tried**.

Comment: @DavidPostill Oops, sorry. Is this an official policy of the site? If so, could you share a link so that I can learn more. Thanks! :-)

Comment: It's not really an official policy, but think of it this way - if you haven't tried it you can't be sure it will actually solve the OPs issue. And if you are not sure then suggest it as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: That page now says "This product has been discontinued and is no longer available"